# .NET 6.0 service runs flawlessly in debug, but fails when started from Service Manager

Tags: c#, .net, window, console-application

I have developed a service using .NET 6.0 that monitors a directory and interacts with an Odoo server. Everything works perfectly when I run it directly or debug it in Visual Studio. However, when I attempt to start the service via the Windows Service Manager, it fails immediately without any detailed error message. The most information I've been able to extract is:

> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Code Details:

The service utilizes IHostedService for its main logic. There's a file watcher (FileSystemWatcher) that's supposed to watch a directory and perform operations once a file is detected. Interactions with an Odoo server are done via the PortaCapena Odoo JSON RPC Client.

Additional Information: The system is running Windows 10, and I've been using .NET 6.0 with Visual Studio 2022.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<FileWatcherService>();
                });
    }
```

```
     public class FileWatcherService : IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        private FileSystemWatcher _watcher;
        private readonly OdooClient _odooClient;
        private readonly string _folderPath;
        private readonly string _fileExtension;
        private readonly DatabaseManager _dbManager;
        private bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }

        public FileWatcherService()
        {
            string currentDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string configFilePathJson = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "setting.json");
            string configFilePathDB = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "localdb.sqlite");
            var settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConfigurationOdoo>(File.ReadAllText(configFilePathJson))!;
            _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            _folderPath = settings.FolderPath!;
            _fileExtension = settings.FileExtension!;
            _dbManager = new DatabaseManager(configFilePathDB);
            var config = new OdooConfig(
                apiUrl: settings.Url,
                dbName: settings.Database,
                userName: settings.User,
                password: settings.Auth
            );
            _odooClient = new OdooClient(config);
        }
        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
            if (!Directory.Exists(_folderPath))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"The directory {_folderPath} does not exist.");
            }

            _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher($@"{_folderPath}", $"*.{_fileExtension}")
            {
                NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.Size
            };

            _watcher.Created += FileCreated;
            _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            var loginResult = await _odooClient.LoginAsync();
            if (loginResult.Succeed)
            {
               IsAuthenticated = true;
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private void FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsAuthenticated)
            {
                SendFileToServer(e.FullPath, e.Name ?? "");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No se pudo enviar por falta de credenciales");
            }
        }
        private async void SendFileToServer(string filePath, string fileName)
        {
            const int maxAttempts = 5;
            for (int i = 0; i < maxAttempts; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
                    await TrySendFile(filePath, fileName);
                    break;
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    if (i == maxAttempts - 1)
                    {
                        _dbManager.LogFileSent(fileName, "Failed", ex.Message);
                    } ;
                    Task.Delay(500).Wait();
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task TrySendFile(string filePath, string fileName)
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            string fileBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
            try
            {
                var model = "register";
                var ecm_file = new OdooDictionaryModel(model) {
                    { "file_name", fileName },
                    { "file", fileBase64 },
                };
                var createResult = await _odooClient.CreateAsync(ecm_file);
                if (createResult.Succeed)
                {
                    _dbManager.LogFileSent(fileName, "Success");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(createResult.Error.Message);
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                _dbManager.LogFileSent(fileName, "Failed", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            _watcher.Dispose();

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _watcher?.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Implemented detailed logging, but it doesn't seem to capture any issues. Checked for any missing dependencies and ensured everything is included in the published folder. Attempted to debug using System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(), but the service still ends without hitting any breakpoints.

Reviewed the Event Viewer, but there are no clear error messages in the Application or System sections. Made sure all resources (like configuration files and database connections) are accessible and in the correct format. Reinstalled the service multiple times.

Comment: Did you create a Windows Service? Your app doesn't look like a windows service. See [This example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service?pivots=dotnet-6-0) for creating a windows service.

Comment: Specifically, `UseWindowsService` is missing, which is the part that responds to service start and stop reqiests.